# Can high-power LEDs remotely control a whole room?

Tags: visible-light, infrared-radiation, light-emitting-diodes

Let's say I have 4 appliances in **rectangular based room** of about 60 **square meters** with **white walls**.

The appliances are using **infrared receivers** with a **filter of 38 kHz**.

Would it be possible to apply a relatively extreme **high-power LED** in the center of the room, instead of one **in front of every receiver**?

I am unsure about the *possible reflections* of the walls oversampling at the filter frequency. Do you think this would work or is the *noise* factor too big for such applications? I was not able to find projects about this, yet.

Thanks so far.

Comment: The simple answer to that is an experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A room with area $60\rm\,m^2$ is about $8\rm\,m$ on a side; call it $x= 10\rm\,m$ to make arithmetic easier.

The time it takes for a reflection to cross such a room is 
$$
t = \frac x c = \rm \frac{10\,m}{ 3\times10^8 m/s} = \frac 1 3 \times 10^{-7} s = 30\,ns,
$$
corresponding to a reflection frequency of
$$
f = \frac 1 t = \rm \frac 1{30}\,GHz = 30\,MHz.
$$
You may like to throw in a factor of two somewhere if you're interested in there-and-back reflection times, or a factor of $\sqrt 2$ if you're interested in corner-to-corner light transmission; whatever.

So your $30\,\rm kHz$ signal pulses are roughly 1000 times slower than the light reflections.  Any reflected light that leaks into a pulse will have to reflect across the room hundreds of times to persist appreciably into the "dark" part of the LED's pulse.  If the infrared reflectivity of your walls were 97% (unrealistically high; [snow has an albedo 0.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo#Snow) when freshly fallen over a featureless landscape), then after 100 reflections the intensity would be $0.97^{100} = 5\%$ of the original. That's plenty of contrast for a pulsed-infrared signal.

Of course every clever idea like yours fails the first time it's implemented, but I think yours won't fail because of long-lasting infrared reflections.

Comment: Sounds completely legit. Will try this as an experiment and comment my notes below my question. Thank you, sir.